# Can I write Java logic in JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee

Can I write Java logic inside JavaScript? If yes, how?

I don't have liberty to make a new class and redirect it there on click of button.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the logic to execute on the client side, then (aside from applets etc) the logic will have to be written in JavaScript. There are tools such as [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) which convert Java to JavaScript, which may help you.

Another alternative is to use AJAX - you don't redirect the whole page when you want to execute the logic, but your JavaScript calls back to the server (which then executes the logic in Java, in your case) and then potentially alters one piece of the UI based on the response.

Answer (score 1):

I found the way:

```
function myjavascriptfunc(){

<% // put java code %>
}
```

Comment: This may not do what you think it does. Scriptlets can be used to output server side state to javascript at loading time. But it is not a dual communication channel between java server side and javascript client as it seems. As @Jon pointed out, you need Ajax, page refreshes or something like that to fire HTTP requests in order to execute server side logic after the page is loaded.

Comment: If you feel confused about what I am saying, try to call a server side method which increases a counter and writes it to the servlet container log through the scriptlet block inside your javascript method.You will understand what I mean.